# Is there some way to convert LSN to a timestamp?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to know if is possible to convert the value of a LSN.

ie: 306239000001950100001 to a date/timestamp.

Something silimilar of `scn_to_timestamp` function in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not related to a date time.

> The LSN is shown as a three part structure. The first part seems to
> stay the same (the 14), the middle part apparently has some erratic
> increases and the last part seems to increase monotonically but it
> resets back to 0 when the middle part changes. It is much easier to
> understand what’s happening when you know what the three parts are:
>
> - the first part is the VLF sequence number.
> - the middle part is the offset to the log block
> - the last part is the slot number inside the log block

http://rusanu.com/2012/01/17/what-is-an-lsn-log-sequence-number/

When using CDC, you can track the changes committed to the related objects by using the

```
[sys].[fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time]
```

And getting the time from the

```
[cdc].[lsn_time_mapping]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-cdc-map-lsn-to-time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thinking about it, wouldn't it be possible to correlate the LSN to a log records (in the ldf file or a backup file)? Point-in-time restore allow us to stop for both LSN and datetime, which suggests that both of these are available in the log records. The question is how to create some user-friendly method of accessing this...